# Page Life Cycle while using Pagemethods

Tags: javascript, c#, pagemethods

I need to call some C# functions (which save some values to the database) from Javascript, and so I'm using multiple PageMethods to do that. I want to show an alert to the user after all this has been done. But I'm not able to understand the order in which the script is being executed in Javascript.

So this is what I have (simplified):

```
var savedchanges = false;

function saveFields(){
    for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
        alert("Just before saving polygon");
        PageMethods.saveCoordinates(arguments, onpolygonsaved, onerror);
    }
    alert("After everything");

    if (savedchanges == true) {
        alert("The changes have been saved");
    }
}

function onpolygonsaved(result){
    savedchanges = true;
    alert("OnPolygonsaved");
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        if (points[0].polygonnum == result[0]) {
            PageMethods.saveSamplePoints(arguments, onpointsaved, onerror);
        }
    }
}

function onpointsaved(pointresult){
    savedchanges = true;
    alert("OnPointSaved");
}
```

The way this works is that, there are 'n' number of polygons, and inside each polygon, there are a certain number of points. Initially, I thought this is how it'll progress:

PageMethods.saveCoordinates --> onpolygonsaved --> PageMethods.saveSamplePoints --> onpointsaved --> Back to saveFields function.

So that, if I put up an alert after the pagemethod in saveFields() based on the value of savedchanges, it'll show the alert to the user after all the points are saved.

But it didn't work that way. So I put up alerts at different locations to check how it is progressing. Suppose there are two polygons, this is the order in which the alerts showed up:

1. Just before saving polygon
2. Just before saving polygon
3. OnPolygonsaved
4. After everything
5. OnPolygonsaved
6. OnPointSaved (for each point of the first polygon)
7. The changes have been saved
8. OnPointSaved (for each point of the second polygon)

In fact, if I'm not imagining things, this order is different everytime I try this, even if the number of polygons/sample points are the same in each case.

Why is this happening, and how to do what I want to do?